# Grails 4.x.x CRUD performance is SLOW

Tags: grails

Upgrade from Grails 3.x.x to 4.x.x and CRUD performance is at lease 4x slower.
Is there any configuration?

performance is slow just on a standard GORM object

Comment: If creates, reads, updates and deletes are 4x slower after you upgraded to Grails 4, something is definitely wrong in the project.  In general GORM is faster in more recent releases and certainly not 4x slower.  Seeing a project configured like yours would be helpful. If you can demonstrate any kind of dramatic slowdown in a sample app, please file a report at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues and share relevant details.  We will be happy to look into it.

Comment: Can you share any additional information on what it is in particular that appears to be 4x slower?